# Instance of a non-templated class using templated constructor interpreted as a function definition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

My issue is best demonstrated by the following code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

class Bar
{
    public: template <class Iterator> Bar(Iterator first, Iterator last) {}
};

void foo(const Bar& bar) { }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::ifstream file("file.txt");

    Bar bar(std::istream_iterator<char>(file), std::istream_iterator<char>());

    foo(bar); // error C2664: 'foo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Bar (__cdecl *)(std::istream_iterator<_Ty>,std::istream_iterator<_Ty> (__cdecl *)(void))' to 'const Bar &'
              // with
              // [
              //     _Ty=char
              // ]
              // Reason: cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'const Bar'
              // No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

    return 0;
};
```

Here are some similar instantiations  of `bar` that don't cause the same ambiguity:

```
Bar bar = Bar(std::istream_iterator<char>(file), std::istream_iterator<char>());
```

and

```
std::istream_iterator<char> start(file);
std::istream_iterator<char> end;
Bar bar(start, end);
```

**My question is**, what is it about the first declaration of `bar` that causes it to be misinterpreted?

note: I'm testing with Visual Studio 2010 (10.0.30319.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArunMu gets partial credit, it is indeed an example of [Most Vexing Parse](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), but that term was coined in Meyer's Effective STL (Chapter 1, Item 6) not Exceptional C++.

It **is** being interpreted as a function pointer (the `(__cdecl *)` portion of the error is a dead give away), and apparently the C++ standard requires it to be interpreted that way. **Does anyone have a chapter/verse citation for that?**

There is also a another solution to provide a disambiguation.  Adding an additional set of parenthesis around each parameter works too:

```
Bar bar( (std::istream_iterator<char>(file)), (std::istream_iterator<char>()) );
```

It's also worth pointing out that the issue is unrelated to the templates, as I had originally thought.

Comment: yeah..got confused with the book name :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is related to "C++ most vexing parse" that you will find in Meyer's Effective STL book.

```
 Bar bar(std::istream_iterator< char >(file), std::istream_iterator < char >());
```

Is being considered as a **function declaration.**

due to which in `foo(bar);` you are sending a function pointer instead :)

Doing like below will have no error:

`Bar bar = Bar(//your arguments here);
foo(bar);`

Comment: FWIW, uniform intialization in the latest standard resolves this by making the preferred intialization syntax be ` Bar bar{std::istream_iterator< char >(file), std::istream_iterator < char >()}; `.  Note the curly braces. See http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#uniform-init

Comment: @ArunMu, The solution you suggest is in the original post ;)

Comment: @ArunMu if you make those corrections, I'll accept your answer and delete mine.

Comment: @luke: I have edited, but its your answer that sounds more correct (the one about adding additional parenthesis :) ). No harm in accepting your own answer :D